# How to get a parameter from a URL encoded?

Tags: c#, system.web

I have the following code to get parameters and their key from a URL:

```
string queryString = new Uri(URL).Query;
var queryDictionary = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);

var paramsList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var parameter in queryDictionary)
{
     var key = (string)parameter;
     var value = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString).Get(key);
}
```

It works perfect. Exception, in `value`, I have the `decoded value`. I would need to have it as it was in the address, before it was decoded. How can I do it? Note that to encoded it after gives different value in some cases.

Comment: doesn't `queryString` give it to you escaped?

Comment: escaped? sorry I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: encoded is same as escaped

Comment: yes, however unless I want to parse string manually, the only way to obtain it I found is this: var value = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString).Get(key); and it decode it...

Comment: Yeah, you can parse it or do as Mario says. But there are different forms of encoding and I'm not sure `UrlEncode` will exactly encode it like it originally came in every time.

Comment: it didn't just tried :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding is happening in your first line already:

```
string queryString = new Uri(URL).Query;
```

Presumably you want to avoid writing your own code to extract the Query part from a URL. Which is sensible. You can still rely on the `Uri` class to do the parsing for you:

```
var uri=new Uri(URL);
var queryString= URL.Replace(uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path), "").TrimStart('?');
```

———————————————————————————————————

(

```
var URL="http://a/b/?d= @£$%% sdf we  456 7 5?367";
var uri=new Uri(URL);
Console.WriteLine(uri.Query); // Already url-encoded by the Uri constructor
var queryString = URL.Replace(uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path), "").TrimStart('?');
Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString)); //Not encoded!
```

)

(As an aside, [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net) helps)

Answer (score 0):

A possible way of doing this is to encode it back:

```
var encodedValue = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value);
```

ASP.NET automatically calls HttpUtility.UrlDecode when you access the query string.

This is a bit dirty, but should work fine.

Comment: the problem I have is that it is then encoded, but it is changed sometimes